# How can I better ask this question about finding example code to learn from?

Tags: support, specific-question, asking-questions

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26415089/where-can-i-find-a-tcs-example), but as you can obviously see, it was not well-received.

[image: Deleted question content]

I am wondering how I can make such a question a good question? I tried asking the question several times but deleted the text and started again, and never really got a satisfactory result on how to ask it.

Before re-posting some sort of similar (actually good) question, how should I post that particular sort of question, and what specifically in that question could I have improved?

Comment: (I did not downvote this question.) The question is "Where can I find something?", and those types of questions are off-topic. It's clearly covered by the off-topic close reason "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam." Your question asks for a link to an example, which would clearly qualify as an "off-site resource". (Also, note that since you've deleted your question, it's only visible to 10K+ reputation users.)

Comment: @KenWhite if I didn't delete it, I would get a lot more downvotes by "advertising" it here.

I personally would say it's more of a "how can I do something" rather than a "Where can I find something".

Comment: @KenWhite Also, asking for a code example is an "off-site" resource? Mind explaining that?

Comment: @Joehot200, read the title of your post again.  You are *clearly* asking "where to find" (presumably not on SO) a particular resource (in this case: code).

Comment: A quick Google search rendered a lot of sites with tutorials and source code from OpenGL and nVidia. Try it out, see what happens, then come back, post your results.

Comment: `I am looking for a complete, working example of a Tessellation Control Shader`: Either you are looking for a link to an off-site resource or you are expecting somebody to write a blog post sized (or bigger) response. Neither of which are something you can expect from SO. It's not that the question is "bad" and certainly everybody has experienced the kind of frustration you are having with not quite finding the right resource, but SO isn't the place to solve that particular problem. There must be OpenGl related forums that could point you in the right direction. Or books.

Comment: You have been bitten by boolean nature of software developers. As literally written, your question would be considered off-topic. If someone would take 2 minutes, read your question, and understand what it is you are asking for, I think they would find that the core of your question is very much on-topic for Stack Overflow, and could be edited to make everyone happy. People don't do that often these days, it seems.  They would rather take a guideline and apply it as a black-and-white rule.  Sadly, this is the state of our community, and your question will need to fit that box to get an answer.

Comment: @Brad Its awfully broad. It *could* be salvageable, but I doubt it would take 2 minutes to fix. Granted, I'm no shader expert, but my intuition is that they take a long time (and a lot of code) to do, more than normal for an SO post, and so is **too broad**.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I hadn't thought of the "too broad" classification... I don't necessarily disagree in that regard, and can see where you are coming from.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Your best bet is to simply ask Google. As @KenWhite points out, recommendations for "a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource" are off-topic on SO. There's really no way to massage such a question into an acceptable form.

Comment: I have already spent five hours on google with absolutely no results. It's absolutely insane as to how little information there is.

Comment: Also, I was looking for an example of code, which I do not think fits into "a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource". So how actually is it specifically off-topic?

Comment: @Joehot200 It fits into "other off-site resource"

Comment: There is no amount of time spent on google which will magically turn an off-topic SO question into an on-topic SO question. If you're looking for something and five hours on google didn't help you find it, then you have a frustrating problem, but you still don't have a good SO question.

Comment: @Joehot200 Code is also considered a resource. And you are asking where to find example code (resource). Which is off-topic. It's worth noting that, if you requested help in creating your own shader, it would probably still be closed for being **Too Broad**. You would have to get your shader pretty much working and ask for help with your current code.

Comment: "You would have to get your shader pretty much working and ask for help with your current code."

OK, I will do this. Thanks!

Comment: @Joehot200 Just make sure you fully explain the problem and what you are trying to achieve while avoiding sounding like, "Here is my code, here are my expectations, fix it for me"

Answer (score 11):

> How can I better ask this question about finding example code to learn from?

It's nothing to do with your wording (which is all fine), grammar, spelling, which Stack site you ask on, or how you portray your message.

You cannot ask "what's the best.." or "Where do I find.." on a *Q&A* site.

Where do I find? Google, or other search engines which *find things* on the internet.
Not really Stack which allows people to ask specific questions on code, or a clear scenario they have which doesn't work, either way something which can bring about a clear cut answer.

**Basic idea behind the Q&A format:**
With your question, no one can give you a *straight forward answer*. While it's not entirely this strict, on Stack you need to aim for scenarios like:
Q = "What is 2+2"
then people can *answer*
A = "4"

Or, Q "I have this function, and it doesn't XYZ" - A "It's because you don't pass in the variable" (etc).

**Alternative**
Try a good dev/tech/webmaster forum. As forums allow a bit more "discussion" towards things like "Hey folks, I'm looking for X, has anyone come across anything like this, and if so where?".
Forums are geared up for such things, discussion and more varied topics with loose questions.

Comment: "What is 2+2?" isn't a very good question either, though [Math.SE can shed some light on how we can know 1+1=2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/95069/160318).

Comment: That specific question isn't, no. It was the logic I was referring to, as in it can be directly answered. "not entirely this strict" "scenarios like"

Comment: A sister site was launched few years after this answer was post [Computer Science Educators](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/) . They allow questions from self-learners asking for guidance for teaching themselves, i.e. asking for resources. See [my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421418/1595451) for further details.

Answer (score 7):

(Disclaimer: I'm not a very experienced meta user so please just let me know if this is incorrect advice)

If you have a question that is not appropriate for Stack Overflow's strict Q&A format (as requests for external resources are), but you still think you could benefit from the experience, knowledge and professionalism of the community, I'd recommend heading over to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/). Plenty of smart people from the community are there and while most of SO's policies are still in effect (e.g. don't be offensive), you're not restricted to the main site's format and rules for asking and answering questions.

Even if no one in chat knows where to find an example, odds are one of them will be good enough with Google to point you in the right direction.

Comment: That would be a borderline chat topic IMO. That said, chat is moderated differently, and you *might* get some help. Still; starting and then asking a question about it is still a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you are honestly interested in self-learning programming, [**Computer Science Educators**](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com) might help you by provinding CS educative guidance and pointers to educative resources. They might not provide you the raw code that you are asking in the referred main site question but they could help you to identify the CS / programming knowledge and skills required to achieve your goal.

More specifically, they might not provide the "complete, working example of a Tessellation Control Shader" for you to experiment and modify but they could *guide you to take the best path to learn*  to use stuff like Tessellation.

---

As mentioned in previous answers, all of them from 2014, asking for any kind of *external resources* is off-topic in Stack Overflow but there are other sites in the network that allow such questions. Specifically questions asking for *self-learning programming guidance* are on-topic in , a sister site which private beta started
5 years ago according to their [Area 51 proposal page](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92460/computer-science-educators) (`<span title="2017-05-23 19:00:00Z">5 years ago</span>`). They have [`resource-request`](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-request). From this tag excerpt:

> For questions requesting teaching/classroom resources for a specific topic or lesson. To get a good answer, ensure your request is specific to a certain type of resource, and does not invite excessively broad or opinion-based answers. Check some of the highly voted example questions in this tag to see how to ask a good 'resource request'.

On CSE questions from self-learners are welcome understanding them as people teaching themselves.

Before posting a question there, please bear in mind that compared with Stack Overflow, CSE is a small site primarily pointed to people who teach Computer Sciences stuff, including programming, but contrary as happens in Stack Overflow, answers with raw code aren't very common as they are more focused on the CS learning-teaching process rather in writing code.

It's worthy to note that their [FAQ](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/q/203/12659) point new users to their question sandbox and that nowadays the question sanbox chat room is redirected to the main chatroom.

From CSE Meta

- [Are questions about self-learning on-topic?](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23/12659)
- [What does a new member need to know on this site?](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/q/203/12659) (FAQ)
- [When are "how do I learn X" type questions on topic here?](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/q/470/12659)

Comment: This doesn't cover any new ground that the original answers didn't.

Comment: @Makoto Thanks for you feedback. [Jame's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274628/1595451) ("Try a good dev/tech/webmaster forum") doesn't point to any specific place, here I'm suggesting a sister site.

Comment: May I point out that this question was asked 8 years ago? (I was also 14 years old at the time!). Upvoted anyway because I didn't know about CSE.

Comment: @Joehot200 Thanks. CSE is newer than the question as well than all the previous answers.

Comment: Does "teaching/classroom resources" actually cover raw example code? All of the linked meta threads are more in line of resources purposely made for teaching. Searching the site for "example" questions I only found people *describing* examples in their own words and giving links as references.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi [`resource-request`](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-request) has some questions close to what the OP is asking... what I have seen so far they don't provide raw code but educative guidance and pointers to specific learning and teaching resources. It's worthy to note that their FAQ point new users to their question sandbox and that nowadays the question sanbox chat room is redirected to the main chatroom.

Answer (score -8):

A lot of questions on Stack Overflow are downvoted and closed as they are considered too broad for the site. In my opinion this has a everything to do with there being no place for the **beginning programmers** on any of the Stack Exchange sites. I know '*Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers*' but then again, everyone has to start somewhere and is in need for some guidance every now and then. You could be enthusiast but still don't know anything about programming.

A question like

> could you give me some code to calculate the difference between a
> donkey and a duck

should be closed, as there is no effort showing at all.

On the other hand, a question like

> I'd like to create a donkey and duck generator in JavaScript. Can you recommend me a good starting point, as [this link] and [this link] are a bit too complicated for me as a beginner?

involves no code at all, but deserve an answer somehow. The poster is not asking to write code for him, just a piece of advice where to start.

Of course, Google is your best friend, but it isn't always that obvious what to Google if you're not a native English speaker or don't know what specific search terms to use. I've seen some pretty useless search results when googling while I didn't exactly know what I was looking for, but only had the general idea *would this be possible in this language*.

So (still in my opinion) it might be time to start some kind of Stack Underflow site, where the beginning or unknowing programmer can have a go. It has two advantages: one being people like the OP get some answers, and two Stack Overflow would be a cleaner place for the real coding questions.

Comment: Why would the people who can actually answer the questions go to "Stack Underflow"?

Comment: You might have a point there. Some kind of community sence? I wouldn't mind helping some people out every now and then.

Comment: The problem with such places is that they tend to become flooded with questions from people who aren't inclined to learn, but seek a complete solution for their specific problem. Often without providing enough information to even guess at what the problem might be. On top of that, many of these people can't even be bothered to say "thank you" after you spent hours on finding out what their actual problem is, and then solving it for them. That's not "community sense", that's a grind, and I can fully understand anyone who doesn't want to put up with it.

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't have a completely homogeneous culture; in some sense it's a federation of tags, some of which are more forgiving than others.  I mostly frequent the R tag, where users often come from a data analysis background rather than programming, so a little more leeway is accepted compared to some other tags.

Comment: The *Stack Underflow* concept has been discussed a number of times, never having a decent argument in favor and everything against. I wish when I was a beginner there was such a vast archive of programming knowledge as [so], folks complaining they don't have space here should get a grip and start improving their research skills.

Comment: [cont] as a matter of fact, we are all beginners in everything but our domain, I love when starting to learn something new and go advancing fast thanks to all problems already solved and documented at SO. And answering stuff while learning, boom! :D

Comment: Few years after this answer was post, [Computer Science Educators](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/) was launched. They allow questions from self-learners asking for guidance for teaching themselves, i.e. asking for resources. See [my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421418/1595451) for further details.