# When is asking for examples a close reason?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, scope

I understood from previous questions (e.g. [How can I better ask this question about finding example code to learn from?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274625/how-can-i-better-ask-this-question-about-finding-example-code-to-learn-from)) and the off-topic/too broad flag reasons that questions asking for tutorials, examples, or other off-site resources were not good questions.

I recently came across [How do I implement modules using Typescript 1.5 and AngulaJS 1.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31637670/how-do-i-implement-modules-using-typescript-1-5-and-angulajs-1-4) as a review audit, however, and the system/community seems to consider this to be a good question.  Can someone explain why the second one is a good question and the first is not?

Comment: Question is definitely too broad, asking for leenks.

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300560/

Comment: @KevinB thanks!  That helps explain the upvotes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Asking for examples without showing efforts of OPs own research and showing the particular code related problems is off topic in the way as looking for 3rd party resources.

StackOverflow isn't a code writing service, or replacement for the Google search engine.

Comment: I completely disagree with this entire answer. Asking for an example of how to do something is the same thing as asking how to do something. How-to questions _are not_ inherently off-topic. Any question can be too broad, unclear, primarily opinion based, or off-topic for any other prescribed reason; but the fact that it is asking how to do something does not in and of itself make the question off-topic. A question lacking research effort is a reason to downvote the question, not close it. And Stack Overflow is a code writing service. We provide the service of writing code for people.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of questions boil down to:

> How to do X?

And any good answer to such a question (imho) would also contain an example. Asking for an example is not necessarily a reason to close a question, even if it shows little to no research effort.

Whether or not people want to downvote is up to them, but I don't consider a question off-topic unless it is particularly broad (like someone posting their giant homework assignment, usually consisting of *multiple* questions), or is a request for debugging help that does not include a working MCVE (you can't reliably answer such a question if you can't reproduce the exact problem). Perhaps that is also why `"This question doesn't show enough research effort"` is not an official off-topic close reason.

---

Coming to your examples. The first question is off-topic because it specifically asks for an off-site resource. Although theoretically it could be modified to ask for an example, the way it is stated would make it too broad, since it basically asks for a complete software project to play with.

The second question you linked does neither. It asks for an example for a succinct case, and a potential answer to that question would be of reasonable size (a few paragraphs). (Whether the selected answer is good is another matter).