# This question needs to be reopened

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

The question *[How to use IFS_READ & IFS_WRITE services?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72286051/2296441)* needs to be reopened. It is looking for an example of how to use a specific API provided by DB2 for [IBM i](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_i). The original close reason (asking for third-party tools) is invalid, as is the reason given for leaving closed (original reason not resolved).

The problem is that this platform is not well understood by the community, and when folks don't understand a topic, they frequently vote to close, or vote to leave closed. None of the close votes came from anyone with experience with this platform, and I suspect the leave closed vote came similarly from someone without any experience in the platform. I did explain the situation to the one close voter who left a comment, and that person reversed their close vote. Can someone please go submit the last reopen vote so an answer can be provided?

Specifically, the OP asked for a simple example of using the IFS_READ or IFS_WRITE API from the [COBOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COBOL) language. These API's are hidden in a strange place in the IBM documentation, and the examples provided are for [RPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_RPG). Someone unfamiliar with the platform or its capabilities might have a difficult time wading through all the various manuals trying to find and connect all the various bits and pieces to get a working example. If the question were open, an answer would be easy to provide.

Comment: *"none of the close votes came from anyone with experience with this platform"* One of the close voters has a score of 381 and 126 posts in [[tag:cobol]]; I wouldn't say that's someone without experience. Another vote from someone with a score of 404 and 138 posts.

Comment: The OP, or a friendly contributor with free time, should edit that question into a How To request rather than a Find/Provide me an example one. This is just a case of someone being unfamiliar with the norms of this Network. If you have an answer that you'd like to provide, you'd probably also be among the best people to edit it into shape (you could even earn a quite rare badge for doing so)

Comment: Related: [When is asking for examples a close reason?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302196/when-is-asking-for-examples-a-close-reason)

Comment: _"I did explain the situation to the one close voter who left a comment, and that person reversed their close vote."_ Well, then explain in laymans words and comprehensively, what you believe most voters don't seem to understand, and why the question should be reopened here as well.

Comment: While "seeking recommendation" close reason might be misleading, the question is also *unclear* on what is the goal. Asking for any examples is off-topic because there's no specific issue to solve. It might be good for Documentation, but [alas](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation) ...

Comment: related discussion at SE.SE meta: [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260)

Comment: @Larnu The OP obviously has limited IBM i experience. The API they are asking about is not a COBOL API, but a DB2 for i API. The only reason for the COBOL tag is that they want to know how to use the API in COBOL which is possible. The only score I am looking for when determining if a close voter has experience on the IBM i platform would be [db2-400] or [ibm-midrange].

Comment: Tag score is a quite ineffective way of knowing what someone *doesn't* know.

Comment: worry less about other people's experience and instead act on the post. If people think it's unclear, it's far more effective to improve that than to dispute that people think it's unclear (or any other close reason).

Comment: @KevinB That is true, but it is a somewhat obscure platform, and a lot of folks under 40 either have not heard of it, or don't know it's capabilities. I don't expect everyone to have a great understanding of it.

Comment: @KevinB Then use unclear as the close reason, or ask for clarification. [ibm-midrange] is a somewhat obscure tag with not many answerers. When folks who don't understand the platform close questions, it is difficult to get them re-opened so an answer can be given.

Answer (score 16):

If you think the question was misunderstood then the proper course of action is to edit it to remove the ambiguity. In this case, it seems that users thought the question was looking for tutorials. Maybe the question can be rewritten to better explain what it is asking for.

I don't know COBOL, but I took a stab at trying to improve it. IMHO it doesn't look like it's asking for recommendations anymore.

Comment: I fully understood the question immediately. Largely because I know what the API's mentioned are, and how to find them in the documentation. But the question is closed by folks who didn't understand. I tend not to vote on questions when I don't understand the underlying technology. I wish others did so as well.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy you don't always know what you don't know.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy Unfortunately, the site wouldn't do well with that mantra. The question needs to be clear even to a complete noob in programming. It's the responsibility of the question asker to ensure that people can't find a reason to close it.

Comment: I have to note that the original version was closed by a user with silver COBOL badge, a user with bronze badge, and another user with at least 2 posts in COBOL. I wouldn't assume that a question is closed because someone "doesn't understand the underlying technology", @jmarkmurphy. If I were one of those users, I'd be, quite frankly, offended by this statement. That said, the edits made to the post overall made it clearer, so I cast the final vote to reopen. Not sure we didn't just waste time on the question, but still.

Comment: And that's probably why folks seem to think SO is unfriendly. Sometimes when you have questions, you just have questions.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine but the question was only tangentially related to COBOL. The API in question is not a COBOL API. But it is one that is exposed to COBOL. You can't go to the COBOL manual to find out how to use it. You have to go to the DB2 manual, and then you also have to know how to embed SQL in COBOL.

Comment: @KevinB that is very true.

Comment: Same, @jmarkmurphy. At least 2/3 users have non-negligible experience with DB2 on the site. And all 3 - with [tag:ibm-midrange] as well. However you put it, calling users incompetent just because you disagree with the closure is wrong. The closure was, in my view, incorrect (hence, the VTR), but I'd really avoid statements like "when folks don't understand a topic, they frequently vote to close".

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine Sorry, I'm not trying to offend anyone. But this tag is obscure, and it is often combined with much more common tags like [SQL] and [python] and [java] and that often gives a false impression because an answer by a python expert to a [python] question that is only tangentially related to [ibm-midrange] will give them a point. I guess my comments came not so much from the score, but from the confusion. Granted, that is also a bad barometer as well since no one can possibly be an expert on all things IBM i either.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine The frustration is due to the difficulty of getting valid questions re-opened due to the low volume nature of the [ibm-midrange] and directly and uniquely related tags.

Comment: Questions being closed for being unclear or ambiguous isn't unfriendly, @jmarkmurphy . If you really did understand it so well then the right action was for you to fix it so it wasn't ambiguous, as mentioned, so that the OP gets the experience they want, and they get a friendly experience of having their question fixed. Don't, however, mistake a lack of additional friendliness as unfriendly; not being (overly) friendly doesn't make someone/something unfriendly.

Comment: @Larnu So the guy who doesn't even know enough to ask a good question shouldn't even be here? I'm saying that though the question might have been unclear to someone who didn't know what those api's were, it was clear enough for me to give an answer which I am happy to do. I don't think all questions have to be clear enough for a complete noob to understand it. There are quite a few questions here that I have no idea about, and would not even attempt to say whether it was clear enough for someone to give an answer.

Comment: *"So the guy who doesn't even know enough to ask a good question shouldn't even be here?"* Where did that come from @jmarkmurphy?

Comment: *"I don't think all questions have to be clear enough for a complete noob to understand it"* the community, however, disagrees with you; they should be clear so that a noob can consume and understand it as we want **everyone** to be able to read and understand the content here. You are focusing too much on the API here, and your knowledge. It doesn't matter if your crystal ball is working; no one else's is.

Comment: @Larnu It is a beautiful, but unattainable goal for everyone to be able to read and understand all the questions and answers here. Some questions and answers require a certain amount of understanding, and if we cull them out because a complete noob can't understand them, then a large number of the hard questions have to go away.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy btw, the question has been reopened. I guess it's better for you to post the answer first before the situation may change again in the future. I personally hope to not let this chance be missed so that I can understand that the question is really on-topic. Perhaps it's also a chance for the [Lifejacket](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8841/lifejacket) badge.