# Questions looking for an example

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons

I was within a review process of close votes I faced a question which was asking for an example, I suddenly thought this would be marked as:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
>   library, tutorial or...

I did so and got this:

[image]

Although [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49650224/an-example-of-the-use-of-a-friend-specifier-in-a-destructor) hasn't got a close vote and was in review queue for an audit, I thought I was casting the right vote. I did a search about *questions asking for an example* on meta and found [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274625/how-can-i-better-ask-this-question-about-finding-example-code-to-learn-from/274735#274735).

Should I leave these kind of questions open or cast a close vote? I think I'm missing some points.

Comment: I don't see this question as: "Please provide me some code." I read is as: "Is there a case where a destructor with a friend specifier is meaningful?"

Comment: Trying to destroy Q+A with 19 helpful votes will always get you to fail an audit.  What else would you expect?  Such audits are constructed intentionally to verify that a reviewer pays enough attention to the Q+A.  Fwiw, having [php] chops doesn't help much, the question is entirely reasonable.  The friend case is quite unusual and any C++ programmer would like to see how that could be practical.  There is no shame in Skip.

Comment: @HansPassant I didn't get you with *19 helpful votes* clause but I'm sure the person who is *trying to destroy* is the person who says *having [php] chops doesn't help much*. I don't see your comment ethical.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question is well-formatted, with links, code fonts and all, likely written by someone who knows how to ask, I would have clicked on "Looks OK" only for those signs. Moreover, it asks for an example of use of some tricky construct, doesn't look for a tutorial.

Besides, sharing my personal experience, sorry to spoil how the audit system works: I never saw a *bad* question in the low quality queue, only bad answers (and I reviewed almost 7000 posts in that queue).

It seems that most of questions are there for audits (just in case you didn't notice the "Question" title).

So if you have a doubt, follow the question link to see if it's an audit. It's very likely to be one. It's *not* cheating, the queue even provides you a *link* to navigate, so it's even *encouraged*

[image]

Comment: Teaching people to defeat the audits doesn't seem like a good way to approach this question...

Comment: I don't see any harm in going to the question itself. It's well known that there is more information and context visible, and it certainly means the reviewer is paying attention. If you see a question and think "hmm, looks audity" so you go and investigate, you are paying attention which is what the audit is looking for.

Answer (score 17):

The question definitely should not be closed. The issue typical of "I'm looking for an example" questions which motivates a separate clause in that close reason is not about examples per se, but about *off-site* examples. In the question you mention, it is clear that what is expected instead is an answer that provides a short, self-contained demonstration of the described behaviour. The two answers there consist in precisely that.

Comment: Not a domain expert so I cannot comment on the worth and relevance of that particular issue. Its wording, however, makes it reek strongly of your average `-10` voted "plz give examples of class inheritence in C++". It might be advisable to [edit] *this* question, lest it be an example for others (as in "but that well-received question also asks for examples!").

Comment: @usr2564301 While improvements are of course welcome, the only thing that would remove the potential for it to be misused as an excuse for leaving something else open would be editing away the word "example". I don't think that is necessary, as that word isn't a problem in and of itself.

Comment: This answer currently has four downvotes, and yet no one has posted an answer or a comment advancing a different stance (usr2564301's comment doesn't challenge the main point I'm making). It would be useful to know what the counterargument is.